# Workaround for NOT and IN

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a desk reservation app and use the code below to see if the chosen desk is available, but get a delegation warning for using `Not` and `In`. I know that the reservation list will have more than 2,000 records (changed from the default 500). Initially I thought a `For` loop might work only to find there is not such thing in PowerApps. Is there a workaround?

```
Filter(
    Desks,
    Not (DeskID in Filter(
        DeskReservations,
        ReservationStartTime <= DeskReservedFrom && ReservationEndTime >= DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationEndTime > DeskReservedTo && ReservationEndTime < DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationStartTime > DeskReservedFrom && ReservationStartTime < DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationEndTime > DeskReservedFrom && ReservationEndTime < DeskReservedTo
    ).ReservedDeskID),
    Building = ReservationBuilding, Active = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I have done, I created a collection that stores all the reservations for the date and time selected. Since Filter is delegatable it will capture all the reservations.

```
ClearCollect(
    AvailableDesks, 
        Filter(DeskReservations,
        ReservationStartTime <= DeskReservedFrom && ReservationEndTime >= DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationEndTime >= DeskReservedTo && ReservationEndTime <= DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationStartTime >= DeskReservedFrom && ReservationStartTime <= DeskReservedTo || 
        ReservationEndTime >= DeskReservedFrom && ReservationEndTime <= DeskReservedTo, 
        ReservationBuilding = ReservedDeskBuilding, ReservationCancelled.Value = "No"
    )
)
```

I then use this collection to check to see which desks are not in the collection and thus free for reservation.

```
Filter(
    Desks,
       Not (
            DeskID in AvailableDesks.ReservedDeskID
            ), ReservationBuilding = Building.Value, Active.Value = "Yes"
    )
```

I do still get a delegation warning but I believe that this is from the Desks lists but as there will never be more than 2000 desks that should be fine, I have added a warning to the Add New Desk that alerts admin if 2000 desks are used.